# how can we deal with Label include 3 ordinal values in Machine learning

Tags: python, r, machine-learning

I wonder about creating a prediction model that depend on ordinal categories, I have multi columns that contains most of then a severity level High, Medium, low and I have the label is overall severity, could I create a good model to predict the overall severity using machine learning?

Appreciate any response with many thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [ask] to see the types of questions that are on-topic for SO and the amount of specificity that's really needed. It's preferable that you have a task already that you need help debugging or completing. Machine learning is a very broad field, and what constitutes a "good" model depends on context

Comment: It depends on whether the severity levels in the columns are related to the overall severity, how strong that relationship is, and whether you have enough data to represent it. I'm going to say yes, is is possible, and I suggest you try and learn about "supervised classification" which is the name for your type of problem.

Comment: Thanks dear for your reply, for example I have sample of the features Recovery of agriculture ,Recovery of businesses ,Employment access Access to markets for basic items, and food Provision of government services, so all of them carry 3 ordinal category, the targeted column is also contains the 3 items of category, in fact the targeted column has been calculated by conditions from all features that I mentioned some of them, so in this case how can I design the targeted column for prediction?

Comment: Check out the answer and see if it satisfies your needs

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ordinal regression like the following:

```
$ pip install mord

from mord import LogisticAT
import numpy as np

replace_dict = {'High':3,'Medium':2,'Low':1}

y_values = ['High','Medium','Low']

y = [replace_dict[i] for i in y_values]


X = np.array([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]])
y = np.array([y])

ord = LogisticAT()
ord.fit(X,y) 
ord.predict(np.array([10,11,12]))
```

Comment: Thanks dear for your reply, for example I have sample of the features Recovery of agriculture ,Recovery of businesses ,Employment access Access to markets for basic items, and food Provision of government services, so all of them carry 3 ordinal category, the targeted column is also contains the 3 items of category, in fact the targeted column has been calculated by conditions from all features that I mentioned some of them, so in this case how can I design the targeted column for prediction?

Comment: Just like this example. You just need to modify the replace_dict

Comment: Hello dear, thanks for you response, the think is all my attributes are depend on the values as well as the target feature is contains of 3 values as well High, Medium, low, so in this case I need to convert all of them by One-hot encoding, what about the target feature, I did not get you exam, thanks for your cooperation!